# How impliment one entity set that save images information for all other entites

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity, domain-driven-design

I have something like this:

```
    public class Product{ 
       [some properties] 
       public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImages {set;get;}
    }
    public class ProductImages {
         string fileName,
         string size, ... 
         public Product Product{set;get}
    }

public class Poeple{ 
  [some properties] 
  public virtual ICollection<PersonImage> PersonImages {set;get;}
}
public class PersonImages{ 
  string fileName, string size, ... public Person Person{set;get} 
}
```

... and others entity that have one more table as child as own images;

I want get abstract from all ProductImages,PersonImages and ... , and get to One Entity (table), something like this:

```
public Images {
int size{set;get;} , 
string FileName{set; get;}, ... othes prop
}
```

But what is the best way to reference every record of image table to it's parent

Is Enum Type as a property for image entity a good  solution Enum type, like:

```
Enum BelongTo 
{
ProductTable,
GalleryTabl,
PersonTable,
}

public Images { 
   BelongTo belong {get;set;}
   int size {set; get;}
   string FileName {set; get;}
}
```

with enum i can't have navigation property between parent and childs
what is convinient solution with attention to DDD

Comment: You can use Complex Types in entity framework for this

Comment: Hi @Aju Mon i know it's suit for some prop like Address. What do you mean? could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

if I well understand I would say you have (at least) 2 choices

- TPH
- One Image table + many link table

TPH will leads to many empty columns.

```
public class BaseImage { 
   public int size {set; get;}
   public string FileName {set; get;}
}

public class PersonImage : BaseIMage {
   [Required]
   public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
}

public class ProductImage : BaseIMage {
   [Required]
   public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}

public class GalleryImage : BaseIMage {
   [Required]
   public virtual Gallery Gallery {get; set;}
}
```

That is nearly equivalent to

```
public class Image {
   public int size {set; get;}
   public string FileName {set; get;}

   [Optional]
   public virtual Person Person {get; set;}
   [Optional]
   public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
   [Optional]
   public virtual Gallery Gallery {get; set;}
}
```

===== =====

Or you can use one Image class and ManyToMany relations

```
public class Image {
   public int size {set; get;}
   public string FileName {set; get;}

   public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Gallery> Galleries {get; set;}
}
```

with

```
public class Person {
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images {get; set;}
}
```

this seems to me the cleanest scenario to handle one image bind to several Persons, and several Products...

Comment: is it possible have a child table with "changeable" parent; for example in my scenario every image record in imageTable must know parentId and also tableId; possible implement it in EF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24532070/possible-have-changeable-navigation-property-in-ef

Comment: AFAIK, the answer is no.