# Possible Have Changeable Navigation Property in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I want one image entity set for all enties that have many image like this:

Images Entity Set

```
class IMages {
public string FileName {set;get}


public Icollection<mychangeableEntity> mychangeableEntity{get;set;}

}
```

Instead of

```
IMages {

   public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Gallery> Galleries {get; set;}
}
```

one solution in table level is

```
IMages(id,parentId,tableId, filename,size,...)
myTables(Id,Name);
```

table that get my table's name

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this can't be done.

From a database point of view this would be equivalent to a column having several Foreign Key Constraints to several **different** tables, all having to be valid for any value of the column at anytime.

IMHO, that is not possible or even wishable.

Comment: dear tschmit007 i think so, but i think must use a table that save my tables name and my images table tableId column has relation to this table, and parentId in images just save an id without being a Foreign key